# Mule: Application starts up but I get the following Error Message

Tags: mule

My file upload application starts up fine, but I get the following error on the console:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Domain 'default' is not accessible
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleSharedDomainClassLoader.validateAndGetDomainFolders(MuleSharedDomainClassLoader.java:119) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleSharedDomainClassLoader.(MuleSharedDomainClassLoader.java:45) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.MuleDomainClassLoaderRepository.getDefaultDomainClassLoader(MuleDomainClassLoaderRepository.java:54) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.MuleDomainClassLoaderRepository.getDomainClassLoader(MuleDomainClassLoaderRepository.java:34) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultMuleDomain.refreshClassLoaderAndLoadConfigResourceFile(DefaultMuleDomain.java:70) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultMuleDomain.(DefaultMuleDomain.java:66) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultDomainFactory.createArtifact(DefaultDomainFactory.java:52) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultDomainFactory.createArtifact(DefaultDomainFactory.java:17) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultApplicationFactory.createAppFrom(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:70) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultApplicationFactory.createArtifact(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:52) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultApplicationFactory.createArtifact(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:24) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:269) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:108) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:290) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:100) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.2.jar:?]
INFO  2017-03-13 15:04:51,966 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing this error in Anypoint studio

go to project location and make sure domains folder exists ${ProjectLocation}`./mule/domains/default`  if not create one.

still issue, Pre-check:

```
1) make sure you project code checked in to stash ( dont loss any data)

2)close anypoint studio

3)Go to .mule folder of the your project workspace

4)delete .mule folder

5) start Anypoint studio
```

Comment: This answer helped me well, in my case directory `default` was missing from `/mule-standalone/domains/`

Answer (score 1):

I found it was enough to just kill the java process, which was also using a lot of memory at the time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'default' domain can not be accessed, try to create an empty folder 'default' at below location if no 'default' folder is present.

***$MULE_HOME/lib/shared/***

Deploy your application over a clean build afterwards.

Also, if possible use latest version of Mule.